# Magento {Translation}.csv Spaces-Bug?

Tags: csv, localisation

Why does the translation for `"Total-Weight", "Gesamtgewicht"` does not work,

but the translation for `"Total Weight", "Gesamtgewicht"` not?

---

`"Single Weight", "Einzelgewicht"` -- works

`"Total Weight", "Gesamtgewicht"` -- does not work

What im missing here?

Comment: Where is the instance of total weight you te trying to translate? Is it in a template file

Comment: Yes. In a template i call `<th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->helper('myhelper')->__('Total Weight') ?></span></th>` -- EDIT: Mage::helper(...) also doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried e<?php echo $this->__('Total Weight');?>